# iperf tcp throughput show decrease with increasing number of parallel connections

Tags: ubuntu, tcp, connection, throughput

I have two ubuntu servers connected back to back via 10 Gig interfaces.
These servers have 24 cores.

running `iperf -c <server-address>` shows approx 9.x Gbps.

however `iperf -c <server-address> -P 100` shows approx 1 Gbps

`iperf -c <server-address> -P 1000` shows approx 500 Mbps

i can see that the throughput decreases as i increase number of parallel tcp sessions.

I appreciate any pointers to where i start debugging this (or is this expected - i hope not)

update:

root@asterix:/var/tmp# iperf -v
iperf version 2.0.5 (2 June 2018) pthreads

Linux asterix 4.4.0-173-generic #203-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 15 02:55:01 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

BTW, i tried running 10 instances of iperf3 with 100 sockets each.
I see same issue, getting 1Gbps for 10 Gig link, and 5Gbps for 40 Gig link.

thanks,
-kvh

Answer (score 0):

What version of iperf are you using?  Iperf -v will provide that. We've done a lot of performance scaling work with iperf 2.0.14.  you'll need to compile from source

https://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf2/

You might want to try iperf3 as well

Bob